# WPF – how to attach VisualStateGroups in control template created in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, controltemplate

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            …
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        …
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The alternative of the previous **XAML control template** is the following sample in **code-behind C#**.

```
var rootGrid        = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(TreeViewItem))
{
    VisualTree = rootGrid
};
```

How to attach `VisualStateGroup` in the code-behind version? I assume that I need to target `FrameworkElementFactory`. Method `FrameworkElementFactory.AppendChild()` expects another `FrameworkElementFactory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FrameworkElementFactory is a deprecated way of creating control templates as per [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=netframework-4.8).

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. **The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.**

You can build up the template in code as a string and then use the `XamlReader`'s `Load` method. This would make implementing the VisualStateGroups easy!

I hope this helps.